# update a column field using inner join two tables in postgres and I am getting an ERROR: table name "TblFacultyMaster" specified more than once

Tags: postgresql, join, sql-update

```
UPDATE "TblFacultyMaster"
  SET "TblFacultyMaster".teacher_id = teacher_details.teacher_id
FROM teacher_details
  INNER JOIN "TblFacultyMaster" ON "TblFacultyMaster"."IMR"= teacher_details.primary_reg_no
WHERE ("TblFacultyMaster"."IMR" = teacher_details.primary_reg_no);
```

I am getting this error

```
ERROR:  table name "TblFacultyMaster" specified more than once
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: you should really avoid quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the `create table` statements for the tables in question, some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **NOT** post code or additional information in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html)

> Note that the target table must **not** appear in the from_list, unless you intend a self-join (in which case it must appear with an alias in the from_list).

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

So simple remove the `inner join`. You also need to remove the table prefix of the column to be updated on the left hand side of the `SET`:

```
UPDATE "TblFacultyMaster"
  SET teacher_id = teacher_details.teacher_id
FROM teacher_details
WHERE "TblFacultyMaster"."IMR" = teacher_details.primary_reg_no;
```

Comment: we need to connect the table field

Comment: The tables **are** connected through the join in the `where` clause

Comment: So what is wrong with the update in my answer? What is the error you get? Does it update the wrong rows? Does it write the wrong value?

Comment: ERROR:  column "TblFacultyMaster" of relation "TblFacultyMaster" does not exist
  LINE 2:   SET "TblFacultyMaster".teacher_id = teacher_details.teache...
             

now I am getting this error

Comment: Ah, copy and paste error. Do not repeat the table name in the left hand side of the `SET` statement (see my edit)

Comment: From the minimal information you have provided that is the only answer I can give you.

Comment: i am trying to update a table field on TblFacultyMaster  with a condition when IMR field of TblFacultyMaster matches with primary_reg_no field of teacher_details

https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name

Answer (score 0):

As @a_horse_with_no_name mentioned from the tutorial, the target table should not appear in the from list. You can however achieve this by aliasing the table in the from_list. I have done this before, and it works.